# Order of function execution in Node async/await

Tags: node.js, lodash

I have a doubt in making sure the functions run in sequence and the result from the first call is used in second call.

**DB Function**

```
async runquery(){
 try {
            ...
            const results = await db.statementExecPromisified(statement, []);                 
            return results; 

        } catch (e) {
                console.log("Error - " +JSON.stringify(e));
                return e;
        }
}
```

**Group id**

```
async function groupByID(approvers) {

const group = _.groupBy(approvers, 'ID');

return Object.keys(group).map(ID=> {

  return group[ID].reduce((approvers, cur, idx) => ({
    ...approvers,
    ['NAME'    + (idx + 1)]: cur.ID,


  }), { ID});
})
```

**Final Function**

```
 async function preparePayload() {

                if(levels.length != 0 ){
                let statement= `SELECT * FROM ITEMS ` 
                list = await  runquery(statement)  ;
                id   = await  groupByID(list) ;
            }
  let result={}
      result.ID=id;
}
```

Output from DB : `[{ID:1,NAME:'F1'},{ID:2,NAME:'F2'},{ID:1,NAME:'F3'}]`

Expected Output : `[{ID:1,NAME1:'F1',NAME2:'F2'},{ID:2,NAME:'F2'}]`

But the output is not coming as expected.

```
   [{
        "ID": "2"
    },
    {
        "ID": "1"
    }]
```

I am guessing this is due to sequence of the function execution because when i do `console.log(id)` works as expected but when i assign to the **result** variable it gives unexpected output.

I am not sure if I put the question correctly .Kindly let me know if it needs to be more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code apart from two small changes

- groupByID doesn't need to be async and hence don't need to be awaited
- `['NAME'    + (idx + 1)]: cur.ID,` needs to be changed to `['NAME'    + (idx + 1)]: cur.NAME,`

For simplicity I have removed the db call and replaced it with a promise which returns the result which you have mentioned in your post.

See the working code here - https://repl.it/repls/PepperyGrossForms

It gives me this result

```
{
  ID: [ { ID: '1', NAME1: 'F1', NAME2: 'F3' }, { ID: '2', NAME1: 'F2' } ]
}
```

Hope this helps.